# how can i make small popup type thing appear on a button click that contains two sub-buttons which on clicking goes to their corresponding activities?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

I want to open a small popup or something like that on a button click such that the popup contains two buttons which on clicking goes to their corresponding activities.

Please provide the code as i am totally new to android?

Comment: This is not a "we provide code for you" service. You read tutorials, you try things yourself; and then we help with problems in your code.

Comment: What have you tried/read so far ?

Comment: @AsutoshPanda : i don't know how can this be done !

Comment: @GhostCat : I tried surfing net but didn't get anything similar to this. So, don't be so rude , please!

Comment: I am simply telling you as things are. You see, rudeness depends on the perspective. What do you think that I think about newbie requests that violate the policies of this site? Isn't it rude to join a club and don't care about the rules of the people there?

Comment: @GuneetKaur try to increase your search power, i too face problem searching but eventually i got in the track, read [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), try to search first if you face difficulty consult with your seniors and after searching some stuff, still you can't able to find or understand solution, then do post a question and also provide your links which you have searched.

Answer (score 3):

Yes you can do this with **Dialogs**

use Below Code to make dialog:

```
 AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);  
        //Uncomment the below code to Set the message and title from the strings.xml file  
        //builder.setMessage(R.string.dialog_message) .setTitle(R.string.dialog_title);  

        //Setting message manually and performing action on button click  
        builder.setMessage("Do you want to close this application ?")  
            .setCancelable(false)  
            .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
                finish();  
                }  
            })  
            .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {  
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {  
                //  Action for 'NO' Button  
                dialog.cancel();  
             }  
            });  

        //Creating dialog box  
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();  
        //Setting the title manually  
        alert.setTitle("AlertDialogExample");  
        alert.show();
```

A dialog is a small window that prompts the user to make a decision or enter additional information. A dialog does not fill the screen and is normally used for modal events that require users to take an action before they can proceed.

find details of dialogs in below link:
[Dialogs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can use material alert dialog for this

Check [this](http://www.materialdoc.com/alerts/)!